# In python how do I convert string to dictionary to retrieve a particular value

Tags: python, dictionary

One function returns below String s :
s = 'Power On Enabled: On\nsignalStrength: -050\nip address: 192.168.75.123\n'

I want to read the value of ip address in above string s. 
Used below code :
/* Code */

```
s = 'Power On Enabled: On\nsignalStrength: -050\nip address: 
192.168.75.123\n' 

ipdict = {}
newstr = s.replace("\n",",")
newdict = ipdict.update(newstr)
ip = newdict.get('ip address')
print ip
```

Got below Error :
"dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required"

Comment: You are trying to update a dictionary with a string.  You need to update a dictionary with another dictionary or iterable of 2-tuples

Comment: Please always post the full traceback of an error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s = 'Power On Enabled: On\nsignalStrength: -050\nip address: 192.168.75.123\n'
s = s.strip().split("\n")
d = {}
for i in s:
    key, val = i.split(":")
    d[key] = val.strip()

print d
print d["ip address"]
```

**Output:**

```
{'signalStrength': '-050', 'Power On Enabled': 'On', 'ip address': '192.168.75.123'}

 192.168.75.123
```